# Xamarin.Forms - access Azure Active Directory for Microsoft Login - no result callback

Tags: xamarin.forms, authentication, azure-active-directory, exchange-server

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms application for simple Exchange login.

I am following the approach 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-active-directory-login-in-xamarin-forms/

I am able to get the microsoft login screen. After providing the outlook username and password, there is no response from the server side.

Not even an exception. It is redirecting to the login button page (the current page).

So I am not able to find any solution for that.

I followed the exact same steps from the above article.

Is there anything to do more to get login result from Azure server?

Comment: Got some code that you’ve written?

Comment: @Skin thank you for your comment. I am not sure about your question. I think you are asking for the code that I have implemented. The code is in that link in my question and it is not a good idea to paste every line when we have a link. Can you please go through the link and provide some suggestion?